# Google Map Set Marker on Current Location

Tags: android

I have already done that is google map on set marker in current location(Current Lat/Long).Now i want to set marker from users current location to 1 miles,i was stuck in this how to solve this?.

```
for(LatLng point1 : new LatLng[]{point1, point2, point3, point4})
    {                               
    targetLocation.setLatitude(point1.latitude);
    targetLocation.setLongitude(point1.longitude);
    if(currentBestLocation.distanceTo(targetLocation) < 800) 
        {}
```

In above code the target locations takes point4 latitude longitude only.

Comment: what do you mean by "above half miles"

Answer (score 1):

try with this code

```
GPSTracker gps;

gps = new GPSTracker(SearchLocation.this);

    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        usersearchlat = gps.getLatitude();
        usersearchlong = gps.getLongitude();
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
```

or you can use  some other code for lat,long and use this code-

```
    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext()
                .getApplicationContext());

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(usersearchlat, usersearchlong))
                        .zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

add some perditions like these :-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-
  permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.INTERNET"/>
```

Access_Coarse_location.